# I want to calculate the page load time in Watir or Selenium

Tags: performance, selenium, watir

Here is the scenario:

```
1. Login to a web application with username and password and hit Enter (Start timer)
2. Load the login page (lap timer split, to mark the time for page load )
3. Click on a another page (split the lap timer)
4. Stop the stop watch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any method call in Watir returns how long it takes, so this is a trivial task.

For example,

```
b.text_field(:id, 'uid').set username
b.text_field(:id, 'pwd').set password
time1 = b.button(:id, 'logon').click
time2 = b.button(:id,  'movepage').click
puts "Time One: #{time1} Time Two: #{time2} Total Time: #{time1+time2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Spec being introduced into all modern browsers. Currently Google Chrome, IE9 have it built in and Mozilla is waiting to apply the patch that has been supplied.

This new spec is called WebTimings and I wrote a [blog post](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/selenium-webtimings-api.html) showing how to access it using C#. The way to access it is via javascript so can be used with all language bindings.

The JavaScript needed is

```
var performance = window.performance || window.webkitPerformance || window.mozPerformance window.msPerformance || {};
var timings = performance.timing || {};
return timings;
```

This returns a dictionary like this

```
/* The dictionary returned will contain something like the following.
* The values are in milliseconds since 1/1/1970
*
* connectEnd: 1280867925716
* connectStart: 1280867925687
* domainLookupEnd: 1280867925687
* domainLookupStart: 1280867925687
* fetchStart: 1280867925685
* legacyNavigationStart: 1280867926028
* loadEventEnd: 1280867926262
* loadEventStart: 1280867926155
* navigationStart: 1280867925685
* redirectEnd: 0
* redirectStart: 0
* requestEnd: 1280867925716
* requestStart: 1280867925716
* responseEnd: 1280867925940
* responseStart: 1280867925919
* unloadEventEnd: 1280867925940
*/
```

Comment: Great article, but I'm afraid you are going to tell me we can't do this in Selenium 1.0.8. Is this available in 1.0.8, or is Selenium 2 beta required? Also, the newest timing objects sound like they are not available to Firefox 3 either, is this correct?