# Python Selenium: Looking for ways to print page load time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, download, python-unittest

I am pretty new with using python with selenium web testing.

I am creating a handful of test cases for my website and I would like to see how long it takes for specific pages to load. I was wondering if there is a way to print the page load time after or during the test.

Here is a basic example of what one of my test cases looks like:

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("some URL")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

element = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
element.send_keys("User")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
element.send_keys("Pass")
element.submit()

time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

In this example I would like to see how long it took for the page to load after submitting my log in information.

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245062/how-can-we-get-exact-time-to-load-a-page-using-selenium-webdriver and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360854/right-way-to-test-page-load-time-in-selenium.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for the references. Didn't really help me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way around this by running my tests as python unit tests. I now record my steps using the selenium IDE and export them into a python file. I then modify the file as needed. After the test runs it shows the time by default.