# Selenium Python Wait until all the HTML of a page is Load

Tags: python, html, performance, selenium, loading

I don't really have idea about that so I'd like you to give me some advice if you can.... generally when I use selenium I try to search the element that I'm interested at but now I was thinking to develop some kind of load test so check how much time take a specific webpage to load all the html code present.

Do you have some idea how to know the load time of html without search for a specific element of the page? Ps. I use IE or Firefox

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Yes but the people there replay just letting me know how to load the script so I create a more specific one just for load all the HTML of a webpage.... Do you know how can I do it? How can I wait until all the HTML is load?

Comment: There is no function in Selenium that returns the amount of time it took to load a page, all you can do is use a `time` counter and explicitly wait for a script generated element to be present.

Comment: Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11364694/2781701) useful answer!

Comment: @Rafael yes I know that there is anything that count the amount of time to load a page and I'll use the timer of python but I'd like to know id there is some functionality that dynamically wait that all the HTML have been loaded successfully without point to any specific element of the page!

Comment: @Carlo no, there isn't

Comment: I'm going to have a look to the link that u sent to me ;) tks so much